# Numerical Jacobian matrix

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics

Is there a simple way to evaluate the numerical Jacobian of a "black-box" function (defined only for lists of numerical values, for example)?

I the meanwhile I am using the following based on `ND`:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
jac[f_, x0_] := Table[xtmp = x0; xtmp[[i]] = x; ND[f[xtmp], x, 1], {i, Length@x0}]
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a very dirty trick that is somewhat related to [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) (note that *automatic* differentiation $\neq$ *automated* differentiation). It works for twice differentiable, *real*-valued functions $f$ that

- are implemented for complex arguments but
- do not involve `Re` and `Im` and such things.

Examples are polynomials and everything that is numerically approximated by Taylor expansions or Padé approximations. That's quite a lot but not everything, of course.

The strength of the method is that it needs only a *single* evaluation of the function per directional derivative. The idea is to emulate a monade (in the sense of Leibniz) by using $\varepsilon = \operatorname{i}\, 10^{-8}$ as this squares approximately to $0$ in machine precision. Here is the code:

```
monade = I 1. 10^-8
nD[f_, x : {__?NumericQ}] := 
 Re[1./monade Map[
    f, 
    (ConstantArray[x,Length[x]]+DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[monade, Length[x]]])
 ]]
```

A short test:

```
f[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := Sin[x y];
nD[f, {1., 2.}] - (D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}, 1}] /. {x -> 1., y -> 2.})
```

> {-1.11022*10^-16, -5.55112*10^-17}

The following Taylor expansion shows why it works

```
nDWith1Point[f_, x_] := 1/h (f[x + I h])
ComplexExpand[Im@Normal[Series[nDWith1Point[f, x] , {h, 0, 4}]]]
```

[image]

Experimenting a bit, one can find a 4-point method that has even 4th order accuracy:

```
nDWith4Point[f_, x_] := 1/(4 h) (f[x + h] - I f[x + I h] + I f[x - I h] - f[x - h])
Normal[Series[nDWith4Point[f, x] , {h, 0, 9}]]
```

[image]

The main advantages: 1) The `monade` can be chosen much larger for this, e.g. $10^{-4}$ such that this is much less vulnerable to cancellation errors. 2) It can also be applied to mixed derivatives, leading to a 16-point rule for second derivatives.

I am sure that @J.M. even knows how this differential quadrature is called in the literature...

Oh, and see what we can do, a $2^k$-point rule of order $2^k$!

```
nDWith2PowerKPoints[f_, x_, k_, h_] := With[{e = Table[Exp[2 Pi I/2^k j], {j, 0, 2^k - 1}]},
   1/(2^k h) Total[Times[1/e, f /@ (x + h e)]]
   ];
k = 5;
Simplify[Series[nDWith2PowerKPoints[f, x, k, h], {h, 0, 2^k}]]
```

Actually, this works also with other $N$, not only for $N = 2^k$, but Mathematica does not simplify the above expression enough.

[image]

Look how precise it is for `h = 0.1`:

```
x = 1.`100;
h = 0.1`100;
Re[nDWith2PowerKPoints[Sin, x, 5, h] - Sin'[x]]
```

> 6.22230269105447896725778959568*10^-70

**Edit**

I found out that the reason is the following formula which holds for every analytic function (and in a truncated variant if the function has at least sufficiently many derivatives):

$$ \frac{1}{N \, h}
 \sum_{k=1}^{N} f \Big( z + h \, \operatorname{e}^{2 \pi \operatorname{i} \tfrac{k}{N}} \Big) \, \operatorname{e}^{- 2 \pi\operatorname{i}\tfrac{k}{N}} = 
 \sum_{j = 0}^\infty
 \frac{f^{(N j +1)}(z)}{(N j +1)!} \, h^{Nj}.$$

Comment: What Henrik has done here is called "complex step differentiation", and is valuable if your black-box function can be evaluated at complex arguments. See [this](https://doi.org/10.1137/S003614459631241X) and [this](https://doi.org/10.1145/838250.838251) for more information.

Comment: You flatter me, Henrik :P but the new formula you have does resemble the extensions studied by Lai and Crassidis; see e.g. [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2007.07.026).

Comment: @J.M. Hehe. Thanks for the pointer to that paper. The next step I took is precisely into its  direction. Look, I just found a $2^k$-point rule of order $2^k$, completely by chance (added in answer). And of course that pretty much looks like a Cauchy integral...

Comment: ...and as the paper itself notes, you can even do Richardson extrapolation if you're for some reason not satisfied with the complex step evaluations themselves.

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

*This update corrects my confusion in conflating the Jacobian with the Hessian matrix.*

**Gradient**

[`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) already has support for numerical differentiation of black box functions *(although it doesn't work for mixed derivatives)*. First, here's a function to compute the numerical gradient:

```
grad[f_, x:{__?NumericQ}] := With[{d = Through @ (Derivative@@@IdentityMatrix[Length[x]]) @ f},
    Through @ Apply[d] @ x
]
```

Here is an example using `grad`:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Sin[x y]

grad[f, {1., 2.}]
```

> {-0.832294, -0.416147}

Let's check this with the usual definition:

```
D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}}] /. {x->1., y->2.}
```

> {-0.832294, -0.416147}

The nice thing about relying on the numerical differentiation support of [`Derivative`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative) is that it works with extended precision numbers as well. Here is an example:

```
grad[f, {1`30, 2`30}]
D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}}] /. {x->1`30, y->2`30}
```

> {-0.83229367309428477399513646, -0.41614683654714238699756823}
>
> {-0.83229367309428477399513645900, -0.41614683654714238699756822950}

Very good agreement! *(Note however, as pointed out by @HenrikSchumacher, Mathematica does use quite a lot of black box evaluations of the function to arrive at this answer!)*.

**Hessian**

*(My previous revision unnecessarily provided an implementation of the Hessian, so I won't remove it)*.

To compute the Hessian we will need to deal with mixed derivatives, e.g., `Derivative[1, 1][f][1., 2.]`. Unfortunately, while:

```
Derivative[1, 0][f][1., 2.]
```

> -0.832294

works fine, the mixed version does not:

```
Derivative[1, 1][f][1., 2.]
```

> (f^(1,1))[1.,2.]

To deal with this, the following function creates a set of intermediate gradient functions, which it then differentiates:

```
hess[f_, x_:{__?NumericQ}] := Module[{g, len=Length[x], a, h},
    h = Thread[g[Range@len]];
    MapThread[
        (#[a__?NumericQ] := (Derivative@@#2)[f][a])&,
        {h, IdentityMatrix@len}
    ];
    grad[#, x]&/@h
]
```

Here is an example:

```
hess[f, {1., 2.}]
D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {x->1., y->2.}
```

> {{-3.63719, -2.23474}, {-2.23474, -0.909297}}
>
> {{-3.63719, -2.23474}, {-2.23474, -0.909297}}

The same example at higher precision:

```
hess[f, {1`30, 2`30}]
D[Sin[x y], {{x, y}, 2}] /. {x->1`30, y->2`30}
```

> {{-3.637189707302726781584079, -2.234741690198505777789608}, \
>   {-2.234741690198505777789608, -0.909297426825681695396020}}
>
> {{-3.6371897073027267815840794636, -2.2347416901985057777896079613}, \
>   {-2.2347416901985057777896079613, -0.90929742682568169539601986591}}

Comment: Could it be that "Jacobian" and "Hessian" get mixed up here? Very confusing... Jacobians are _first_ derivatives of vector valued functions while Hessians are (essentially) _second_ derivatives of scalar valued functions. For each scalar valued function, the Jacobian of the gradient equals the Hessian.

Comment: Moreover, the following code snippet tells me, that even the simple function `f` in two variables from your example gets evaluated 102 times(!) to obtain a numerical derivate. That's quite often, isn't it? Here is the code: `Clear[g];c = 0;g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (c++; Sin[x y]);grad[g, {1., 2.}];c`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You're welcome!